# java - HtmlUnits give out ReferenceError='console' not defined

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I'm trying to download a video file from a webpage. It worked flawlessly and I copied the code to another project. However, now I'm getting this error:

```
EcmaError: lineNumber=[1] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[ReferenceError] sourceName=[http://proxer.me/templates/proxer14/js/common.js?18] message=[ReferenceError: "console" is not defined. (http://proxer.me/templates/proxer14/js/common.js?18#1)]
```

This Code (should) accomplish that:

```
public String getIframeURL(String url, int waittime) throws Exception {
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(waittime);
    ifr.add(page.getByXPath("//iframe[@scrolling='no']").toString());
    preIframeURL = ifr.get(0).substring(32);
    for (int i = -1; (i = preIframeURL.indexOf("guest", i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
        pos1 = i;
    }
    iframeURL = "http://" + preIframeURL.substring(0, pos1 + 5);
    return iframeURL;
}
```

Does anyone of you have a clue why I'm getting this error?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the second site uses different JavaScript libraries. Do you use the latest HtmlUnit Snapshot?
If yes please open an issue.

Comment: The thing is, on my main computer at home im not getting this error. Only on the Computer at work. Since we're now using a Proxy, I've added `webClient.setProxyConfig(new ProxyConfig("proxy.*******.corp", 8080);`